# Best approach to adding CoreData model to existing project with custom models in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I have a project with existing custom models that get data from a rest api (or the nsurlcache) in JSON format, but now I need to add a CoreData model. I am getting conflicting information on how to best "merge" my models to new CoreData NSManagedObject ones.

What is the most reasonable and clean approach to do this?

Some problems that I'm having is that my custom model is/was a struct at first, and not class, that's not that big of an issue though.

Next is the fact that I have a lot of "stored properties" here and I'm having issues creating these in the extensions to the CoreData models. I need to have them (or a substitute) because there is a lot of custom formatted data that would be redundant to add in the CoreData model but exists in a very clear way as properties currently. I tried to add this to the main class file, however, I'm reading in a lot of places that the best thing to do is to create your own custom extension class (to not even change the automatically generated stub extension). I do get an error though, that I cannot add stored properties to extensions. Should I just resort to changing all of those to functions? That seems dirty.

And finally, overall, how should I keep my models organized from this point on? Should all of my custom functions be kept in my own (not automatically generated) extension file? Are extension files usually created one per model or a cluster (if they are short and related models)? Should ANYTHING be manually added to either the +CoreDataClass or +CoreDataProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your conflicting information?

You will need to think about the use case of your stored properties.

CoreData objects support 2 different types: transient properties (wont be stored in the persistent store) and non-transient properties that will be stored in the persistent store. That way you can start setting up your model design. Both need to be in the model though.

Use more computed properties for things that dont impact your app's performance negatively. Those you can put in extensions. The others need to be in the model, computed once when importing from your source.

A computed property in your case can look like this: (considering you have a NSManaged var eventDate

```
var formattedEventDate: String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //... set desired format/locale
    return dateFormatter.string(from: eventDate)
}
```

Comment: Ok so let's say I have a field which returns fullName (combining two properties firstName and lastName) - I assume this would be a transient property? And for example a custom formatted eventDate based on localization would also apply as a transient property? In this case where do I define getters/setters for the transient properties, the class that gets generated or my own custom extensions? The same question goes for custom fetching/init/getDataFromAPI functions. Do I add all new functions only to my new own extension file or are there situations when it's better to change the main file?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of what is better stored as a computed property you mentioned at the end?

Comment: Sure, lets say you have a Model with certain stored properties that you want to use to search for this object with NSPredicate, because that is not working with computed properties.
But in the UI you want to have various different formatting of strings for example - there you would use a computed property.
However, if it takes too long to compute (such as complex regex on a huge string), you might have to avoid that and store that value, because it impacts your scrolling performance for example.

Comment: Great thanks. Would mind also sharing your thoughts regarding my questions in the first comment?

Comment: fullName would be a computed property in an extension.
eventDate as a String would also be a computed property. you would only store the Date object itself.

Comment: ok I see, the example you provided in the edit was helpful but in this case I don't seem to need the transient properties, correct? So one more thing I guess is custom fetching/init/getDataFromAPI functions. Do I add all new functions only to my new own extension file? And are there ANY situations where I should change the automatically generated +CoreDataClass or +CoreDataProperties classes to extend functionality.

Comment: No you should avoid modifying those files. Transient properties are not necessary in most cases. Get datafromAPI shouldnt be in your model at all. Create an APIClient with a response parser to import into coredata. But that would be a separate question ...